# Perfect overlap of HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to write a JavaScript function that given any HTML element 
(visible on the screen) it creates another HTML Element to stack above it (so as to cover it)? And then if I resize the page it moves exactly as the component it covers.

(So for instance if I were using getBoundingClientRect it would not work if the original component has the width expressed in percentage)

The function should handle any case whether the element (in input) has margins, paddings, borders, whether its display is block or inline, and so on.

I tried by adding a position: relative to the parent-component and then create a position: absolute on the "cover" component. This did not work, because it does not handle cases like padding or margins.

Note: NO jQuery. Pure 'cross-browser' JavaScript, if possible

Comment: Yes, that's easy, just create an element with `position:fixed;z-index:enough` and set its position and dimensions to the position of the element you want to cover. Then on `window.resize` adjust the position and dimensions.

Comment: @dystroy I don't think so...for instance if I scroll the page  the "cover" component won't be in synch

Comment: Why would it not be in synch ? I frequently do this kind of thing with jquery (elements positionned next to elements, not covering them) and it's always perfectly synchrone in all modern browsers.

Comment: @dystroy if it's in position fixed it means I specify top and left. right ? okay enough that my original component moves (for example if above there is a textarea which is enlarged or shrunk) then the cover won't be above (because it's fixed)...

Comment: I looked at my (jquery based) libraries for this things (menu, tooltips) and you're right : absolute is easier. But it's only a matter of knowing position on screen or in document.

Comment: jQuery was created (in part) to solve cross browser issues. Not saying its impossible but good luck doing it without a good framework. Or have fun re-creating a large part of jQuery to handle cross-browser differences.

Comment: @agrothe The fact I ask a no jquery solution is not that relevant. Even writing a solution for this in jquery would be hard.

Comment: define cross browser compatibility please

Comment: @Sebas I think it's reasonable to say from IE8. It also works on Firefox, Chrome and safari.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest that you apend an element to the element you wish to 'cover', give parent element position: relative, and give the attached element position: absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom: 0; right: 0;

example...

markup:

```
...
<div id="content">
    <div class="cover"></div>
    <div></div>
</div>
...
```

css:

```
.cover { position: relative; }
.cover .mask { position: absolute; top:0; left:0; bottom: 0; right: 0; }
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $('.cover').append('<div class="mask" />');
});
```

this method will allow you to ignore what happens on any resizing...

=========================

Improvement based on feedback...

The padding shoudl be sorted by position absolute, for the border and margin you will need to use some js and set negative margins on the masking element. The demo link I've included only deals with elements with padding/margin that are uniform - if you have elements with different paddings/margins on each side then you'll have to do a little more parsing.

The additional javascript would look something like:

```
var $hideme = $('.cover');
$('.mask',$hideme).css("margin", "-="+$hideme.css('border-width'));
$('.mask',$hideme).css("margin", "-="+$hideme.css('margin'));
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PHPsycho/NE9Zt/)

Comment: It sounds to me like Zo72 already tried this, but it only covers the main area of the element to be covered, not the padding, border, or margin. As I mentioned in my answer, you can compensate for this by setting the top, left, bottom, and right to appropriately-calculated negative numbers.

Comment: @Ian wood I tried that... unless you tell me how to handle margins borders etcetera it won't work... I think it's a good idea but it just does not work in my general case... thanks anyway

Comment: The fiddle isn't working in Firefox for me. Do negative margins do anything with position:absolute?

Comment: yeah just noticed that one - I'll have a look and update. negative margins should affect absolutely positioned elements.

Comment: @Isn wood... it's getting there I noticed a few errors if the div does not fit a page... but looks promising I will test it more ...pity you had to use JQuery

Comment: @Zo72 just noticed the note on OP :P, for cross browser you should really be looking to use jQuery (or similar) - that's part of its core ability. That said that particular code doesn't work crowss browser - work needed on the application of margin values. Check in web-kit (which works) and go from there.

Comment: what about images and inputs? They can't hold content (selfclosing), so you can't append anything to it according to the HTML specs...

Answer (score 2):

written below cover function using jQuery please try out if this work out for you

Hi I have updated code which satisfy your need...

```
function coverDiv(sourceId, targetId){  
    var source = document.getElementById(sourceId);
    var sourceComputed = window.getComputedStyle(source);
    var target = document.getElementById(targetId); 
    var positioningProps = ["float","width","height","left","top","marginLeft","marginTop","paddingLeft","paddingTop"];
    var cssText = "";
    for(var i in positioningProps){        
            cProp = positioningProps[i];              
            if(source.style[cProp] == "" || source.style[cProp] == null)
                target.style[cProp] =  sourceComputed[cProp];
            else
                target.style[cProp] = source.style[cProp];
    }
    source.style['position'] = "absolute";
    source.style['zIndex'] = "1";
    target.style['position'] = "absolute";
    target.style['zIndex'] = "999";
}
```

Try demo here::
http://jsfiddle.net/tushhtrivedi/RDFRm/10/

Comment: thanks but 1) it uses jquery 2) even so I broke it immediately by adding width:80% on source... see http://jsfiddle.net/RDFRm/6/

Comment: it broke immediately I just added display:inline <div id="source" style="display:inline;width:80px;background-color:red;"> and it breaks

Comment: @TusharTrivedi: Congrats for earning bounty. I am still waiting  to hit the first. :)

Answer (score 1):

Adding position:relative to the parent component and position:absolute on the cover sounds workable, actually, as long as you take the padding, margins, and border into account. Set the top equal to -1*(padding-top+margin-top+border-width-top), and so on for the other sides. Do this without setting the width or height, and it'll resize itself to stick its edges where you put them. This will, however, fail to work on components that can't contain divs.

To elaborate:

The problem you're having with this approach is that if you try to cover an element with width:100px; padding:10px; border:1px solid black, the cover is only 100 pixels wide and doesn't cover the 10 pixels of padding or the 1 pixel border. You can compensate for this by setting left and right to -11px instead of 0. You'll have to to this in the javascript function that adds the cover, unless everything you're interested in covering has the same padding, borders, and margin.

Comment: thanks but can you elaborate a little what's  Set the top equal to -1*(padding-top+margin-top+border-width-top) ?

Comment: this might be right but I tried it a few ases and I don't think it works well... maybe I am missing something but there is not enough info to have the perfect overlap thanks though

Answer (score 1):

```
function addCover(id) {
 var element = document.getElementById(id);

 var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
 var cover = document.createElement('div');

 wrapper.setAttribute('style', 'position: relative;');

 cover.setAttribute('style','position:absolute; top: 0; bottom:0; right: 0; left: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; z-index:10;')

 element.parentElement.replaceChild(wrapper, element);

 wrapper.appendChild(element);
 wrapper.appendChild(cover);    

}
```

Comment: Thanks but. It just does not work for so many cases. Imagine my element has width:80% (for example the classic margin:0 auto;width:80%) then it won't work...

Answer (score 1):

So, one element is supposed to completely hide another element? Until what? A given time when it is hidden to display the element underneath it?

Why don't you just ***replace*** the element with a new one, until the time when you want the original element visible? That would solve the scrolling issue.

And much easier to do with pure JavaScript.

Unless you are replacing elements on a framed site, which you shouldn't do in the first place, IMHO.

Comment: the element should cover it until 'for ever'. Replacing the current element is not what I want to achieve (say for instance if I want to put some transparency on the cover)

Comment: Why use JavaScript then? Add an element directly to the code. HTML is far too dynamic with too many browser differences to write a generic function for this. Don't try a hammer when a saw is need type thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a version that works even for fixed or absolute positioned elements, and which doesn't break when a scrolling or reflow changes element's position or size :

```
function cover(el, filling) {
  var c = document.createElement('div');
  c.style.background = filling;
  var els = window.getComputedStyle(el)
  c.style.position = els.position=='fixed' ? 'fixed':'absolute';
  c.style.zIndex = parseInt(els.zIndex)+1;
  document.body.appendChild(c);
  var place = function() {   
    c.style.width = el.offsetWidth+'px';
    c.style.height = el.offsetHeight+'px';
    c.style.left = el.offsetLeft+'px';
    c.style.top = el.offsetTop+'px';
  };
  place(); 
  window.addEventListener('resize', place);
}
```

You call it like this :

```
cover(myElement, 'black');
```

**[Demonstration](http://jsbin.com/ifoseq/12)**

There are two limits :

- it doesn't work correctly for some multi-line inline blocks
- as it involves a script reacting to the resize event, it might be possible with a fast resize to temporarly see the element behind

Comment: no luck. I wrote a simple fiddle to test it http://jsfiddle.net/PU8sm  The problem here is that if I resize a component above the 'myElement' the cover does not move... so listening to window resize is just not good enough

Comment: It's perfectly possible to regularly check for element position but the truth here is that a generic solution working for any case would be much too costly to be reasonable. I *can* add the few lines implementing this polling but with today's state of HTML you'd better use a solution only refined for your real use case. A generic solution here is a bad idea.

Comment: you might be right...I have been wondering if it is possible to get a general solution or not. That's why I put a bounty... I do wonder if there is a 10 line solution or not... yours obviously was just too specific... not sure maybe it's going to be that best...even so... we shall see thanks

Answer (score 0):

Assuming I understand you correctly, the easy(and best) way to do this is nest a element inside the element you want to cover. The outside element should have relative position and the nested element should have absolute positioning(with each side set to 0). Usng z-index for each element, you can layer them on top of each other regardless of padding or margin.

```
<style>
.layer-1 {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
.layer-2 {
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    z-index:2;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
<div class="layer-1">
    <span class="layer-2"></span>
</div>
```

Live Example with only a few lines of code, CSS/HTML only: http://jsfiddle.net/3hBsZ/

EDIT: having re-read the question, I did misread it. Your looking for a javascript solution, not a CSS based one. However, this CSS solution would be more effective and cross-browser than a javascript based one. Just my opinion...

Comment: the problem is not in the CSS solution, which could be ported in javascript. The problem is that you assume that html element is a div (or an element that can have children) which is the incorrect assumption (for example what if it is a button, or a textarea or a input type text, which can not have children

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want

```
//https://stackoverflow.com/a/442474/1989562
function getOffset(el) {
var _x = 0;
var _y = 0;
while (el && !isNaN(el.offsetLeft) && !isNaN(el.offsetTop)) {
    _x += el.offsetLeft - el.scrollLeft;
    _y += el.offsetTop - el.scrollTop;
    el = el.offsetParent;
}
return {
    top: _y,
    left: _x
};
}

function overlap(element) {
this.element = element;
this.overlapper = document.createElement("Div");
this.__constructor = function () {
    var left = getOffset(this.element).left;
    var top = getOffset(this.element).top;
    var width = this.element.offsetWidth;
    var height = this.element.offsetHeight;
    this.overlapper.style.position = "absolute";
    this.overlapper.style.width = width + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.height = height + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.left = left + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.top = top + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.background = "black";
    this.overlapper.style.zIndex = 999;
    document.body.appendChild(this.overlapper);
}
this.update = function () {
    var left = getOffset(this.element).left;
    var top = getOffset(this.element).top;
    var width = this.element.offsetWidth;
    var height = this.element.offsetHeight;
    this.overlapper.style.top = top + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.left = left + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.width = width + "px";
    this.overlapper.style.height = height + "px";
}
this.__constructor();
}
```

the offset of a element function was get on this post
https://stackoverflow.com/a/442474/1989562

i made a fiddle as a example

http://jsfiddle.net/takedownbig/ASuEJ/

it will get the actual position onscreen of the element, to make the element update you must trigger the update function of the object, i recommend to be used like my example.
Works on ie9+ i would like to have this workin on ie8 too :/

@edit: the function does not have all the ways of updates, but if you find them you can simply trigger the update function to fix the actual position and width.

Comment: I will review this one shortly.Sorry got side tracked

Comment: thanks for this. It seems to work but there is hack in your code. That is:  //use this if you really want to update this on any situation
setInterval(function(){teste.update();},50);

Comment: because of the hack I don't think it's a good solution. Really sorry and thanks

Comment: yes, that was helpful...if I could get it to work without the hack it would be the best example

Answer (score 0):

As often, this is a problem that seems much simpler then it turns out to be when you start trying to tackle it. I gave it a go, and though it is not yet 100% to my liking, I will share my results with you.

First I should note that jQuery is perfectly valid cross browser JavaScript, so I can not think of any good reason not to use it. Definitely if you load it from Google CDN or similar, it will probably already be in your users cache. So I went ahead and wrote a small jQuery plugin (my old-school JavaScript is just way to rusty to be honest).

First the code:

```
// jQuery plugin to create overlays
// apply to any container that contains DOM elements to be overlayed
$.fn.overlayDiv = function() {
    // remove any old overlays (could be there on resize)
    $(this).find('.overlay').remove();

    // loop trough the remaining children
    $(this).find('*').each(function() {
        // cache some variables
        var $el =  $(this);
        var $parent = $el.parent();

        // make the parent relative, if not yet absolute or fixed, for easy positioning
        if ($parent.css('position') !== 'fixed' && $parent.css('position') !== 'absolute') {
            $parent.css('position', 'relative');            
        }

        // prepare the css
        var css = {};
        css.zIndex = $el.css('z-index');
        css.position = $el.css('position') == 'fixed' ? 'fixed' : 'absolute';
        css.display = 'block';
        // check if inline or block, and calculate settings appropriately
        if ($el.css('display') == 'inline') {
            // -- inline
            // clone the element and render it on one line
            var $clone = $el.clone();
            $clone.css({
                width: 'auto',
                display: 'block',
                whiteSpace: 'nowrap'
            });
            $clone.insertAfter($el);
            // compare height of element and clone
            if ($el.outerHeight(true) == $clone.outerHeight(true)) {
                // if the $el is on a single line
                css.width = $el.outerWidth(true);
                css.height = $el.outerHeight(true);
                css.top = $el.position().top;
                css.left = $el.position().left;  
                // apply the styling to an overlay div and include it in the DOM
                $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css(css).insertAfter($el);
            } else {
                // if the $el is on multiple lines (we need up to 3 divs to overlay)
                // -- this part of the code needs improving --
                var lineHeight = $clone.outerHeight();
                var totalWidth = $clone.outerWidth();
                var lines = $el.outerHeight() / lineHeight;
                var maxWidth = $parent.width();
                // top overlay
                css.width = maxWidth - $el.position().left;
                css.height = lineHeight;
                css.top = $el.position().top;
                css.left = $el.position().left;
                $('<div class="overlay top"></div>').css(css).insertAfter($el);
                // bottom overlay
                css.width = totalWidth - css.width - ((lines-2) * maxWidth);
                css.top = css.top + (lineHeight*lines);
                css.left = 0;
                $('<div class="overlay bottom"></div>').css(css).insertAfter($el);
                // center overlay
                css.width = maxWidth;
                css.height = (lines- 2) * lineHeight;
                // -- /needs improving -- //
            }
            $clone.remove();
        } else {
            // -- block
            css.width = $el.outerWidth(true);
            css.left = $el.position().left;
            // -- height and top might need to improved if you want collapsing margins taken into account
            css.height = $el.outerHeight(true);
            css.top = $el.position().top;
            // apply the styling to an overlay div and include it in the DOM
            $('<div class="overlay"></div>').css(css).insertAfter($el);
        }
    });
}

// when the window is loaded or resized (not just ready, the images need to be there to copy their position and size)
$(window).on('load resize', function() {
    // apply the overlay plugin to the body to cover all elements, or recalculate their positioning
    $('body').overlayDiv();
});
```

Plenty of comments in there, so I think it should be understandable, but feel free to ask if you want any clarification.

You can see the code in action over here: 
http://jsfiddle.net/pP96f/7/

About the 2 remaining issues:

- The biggest problem is the inline elements that span across multiple
  lines. If you want to cover only the text inside the element, you
  will need up to three separate overlays to achieve this. I was
  struggling with the dimensions (especially the width of the bottom div) and eventually i gave up. Any input
  would be appreciated!
- A smaller issue is the one of the collapsing margins. This should not be to hard to tackle, but I was not sure how you wanted this handled. (And I already spend way to much time on this question...)

Hope my input can be of assistance!

**edit:**

For a version that allows you to select the specific elements you want to overlay, and not just select a parent and have all the children(recursivly) overlayed, have a look at this slightly altered version of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/ARWBD/2/

Comment: sorry I got busy... I will review it as soon as I get a chance

Comment: many thanks but I don't think it works. I amended the test by highlighting just a div id=test. and creating a textarea above and it just did not work. JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ARWBD/

Comment: not sure what you tried to do by adding that counter... I removed it and it seems to work just fine http://jsfiddle.net/ARWBD/1/. Perhaps i misunderstood you, and you want to overlay just some specific elements? Have a look at this slightly altered version then: http://jsfiddle.net/ARWBD/2/

Comment: sorry I should have been more clear... Yes I was just overlaying a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this old thread while googling for something else.

If all you want to do is highlight the to-be-covered element and put some text in the overlay, then you can do this without any javascript, just CSS using :after (the to-be-covered element needs position: relative though).

```
div#source {
    position: relative;
}

div#source:after {
    content: "Covered";
    background: purple;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kfdmta7w/

Answer (score 0):

Try this by using jquery UI [position](http://api.jqueryui.com/position/):

```
 _overlapTwoElements(topElement, baseElement) {
       if(baseElement.length && topElement.length) {
          topElement.width(baseElement.width());
          topElement.height(baseElement.height());
          topElement.position({ my: "left bottom", at: "left bottom", of: baseElement });
       }
    }
```